# Xcode 11.4 - Introduction of Terminal

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode11.4

**Xcode 11.4 release notes** introduced that ***Xcode 11.4*** now has new option to choose **Terminal** instead of **Xcode's Console**. However, I was unable to find the terminal option in [Xcode -> Scheme Editor’s Options tab](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_release_notes)

[image]

Is it actually available just like VSCode(in debug area)? If so, how to enable this option?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently that the option is only available for macOS apps, not for iOS apps. Choose Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme ..., then go to the Options tab:

[image]

Comment: I was expecting terminal for iOS projects, Alas :(